# localhost hard coded in various files on OpenAM

Tags: localhost, openam

I’m following open AM (12.0.0) getting started guide (https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/12.0.0/getting-started) but not able to access the OpenAM login page when I use the server alias name e.g.-
http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/

It keeps showing me the Open AM’s page is loading screen only (index.html).

However when I replace the alias in URL to localhost then it starts showing up the login page correctly. I can see that localhost is hard coded at many a places in various files in OpenAM war file e.g.-

 getServerInfo.jsp

 /config/wizard/step3.htm

Please note that I can access other applications with alias e.g. ROOT or tomcat examples.

Could this hard coding be the reason for the issue?
How to get around around this issue.

Comment: What is the server name of your OpenAM instance? You can see the server name by going to Configuration > Servers and Sites. By default OpenAM can only be accessed if you use the server name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ran the setup page (where you click on "create default configuration") did you access that page using localhost or openam.example.com?

I suspect you did the former, which will set openam's cookie domain to be localhost.

When openam is set up using "create default configuration", it sets the cookie domain to be domain of the Url that you access the page with. It also puts all of its configuration in a directory that matches the name of the war file in the home directory of the user that runs tomcat.

If you want to start again, you can shutdown tomcat and delete that folder. If you followed the steps in the guide, that user will be the user that ran startup.sh, and the folder will be called openam.